# Use a decoder or direct address?

Tags: led, display, led-matrix

I am designing a **RGB LED matrix** of 1:4 scan 16x32 pixels
As it is 1:4 I have 2 options

**Option A:** Use A,B,C,D pins direct address to control the display

or

**Option B:** Use A,B pins only and use a decoder to control the display

Which option would be faster? I have to chain many panels so I have to optimise speed.
Can option A generate more noise in comparison to option B?
It is very important to have minimum noise for the display to have good quality.

As I have to chain 10 displays. If I use a decoder for every display there will be 10 decoders required. Is that delay per display negligent?
But if I use those C and D lines, there will be 2 more lines running through the display.

**Explanation for 1:4 scan rate**

As my display is of 16 rows, 1:4 scan rate means only 4 rows will be lit every cycle i.e 25% of the total display. 1:2 scan rate means 50% 8 rows will be lit per cycle. So for 1:4 Address lines are used to decide will set of rows will be lit. That is why I have 2 options. Either use 4 pins for direct addressing. Or use 2 pins and use a decoder.

I am designing something similar to this display:

[Led matrix](https://learn.adafruit.com/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix)

Thanks!

Comment: What is "1:4 scan"? I've never heard of it. Hit the [edit] link.

Comment: Please show schematic and timing diagram to explain what you mean by '1:4 scan'.

Comment: scan rate gives the % of number of LED's lit in one cycle. In. Therefore address lines are required to select which rows will be lit per cycle. for a display with 16 rows only 4 rows are lit every cycle with 1:4 scan rate i.e 25% of the display. But the cycle is so fast we can never notice it

Comment: people should not have to read the comments in order to understand the question ... please edit your question

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the question

Comment: It's still unclear what your matrix looks like. It seems like what you mean is 4:1 (64 columns x 4 mux groups) vs. 2:1 (128 columns x 2 mux groups). Is this your intention? Because if what you really need is only 32 columms, then you need to mux *16* to 1.

Comment: please check the updated link

Comment: The multiplexing, if any, is done inside the panel. The adafruit page doesn't get into this, but the detailed data sheet will. That said, if you can feed data to multiple panels at the same time the update will be faster than daisy-chaining them. As far as what A,B,C and D on the connector do, you need to read the datasheet yourself and grok what it does.

Comment: I have explained what A,B,C,D does. They are used to select which set of rows are to be turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is what is faster. Because this is an LED display, I assume that people will be viewing this, and not computers or cameras. If that is the case, then either alternative can be plenty fast. It only needs to refresh the LEDs 60 times every second for it to appear to human eyes that it is solidly on. 
 The second question refers to minimum noise. If you mean RF noise, then the slower the circuit and less cycling from high to low voltage, the better, so using A,B,C,D will be best. If by "noise" you mean how the display looks, or that you don't want it to flicker, then just increasing the speed of the circuit can make the display appear to human eyes to have no flicker. Even chaining many panels, the circuit will be able to handle the speed. You'd have to get tens of thousands of RGB LED matrices chained before speed would become an issue.

Comment: your answer makes sense to me. One more disadvantage using the decoder is one more IC will be introduced to the circuit. One more part which may wear out